# Can't get API input list and convert it to json and get its contents

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have an API that as an input I have:

```
myMedicineJsonList=[{"medicineType":"ketamine","medicineDose":"5 drops","medicineDiode":"IV"},{"medicineType":"adrenaline","medicineDose":"5 drops","medicineDiode":"IV"}]
```

I need to get its contents and save it in a table in a database.

Currently I'm using the following code:

```
public partial class medicines
    {
        public int medicine{ get; set; }
        public String medicineType { get; set; }
        public String medicineDosage { get; set; }
        public String medicinePlace { get; set; }
    }

public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<String> Insert_call_info( List<String> medicineList)
        {
            using (EMSMVCEntities entities = new EMSMVCEntities())
            {

                entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
              
                try
                {
                    var myMedicineJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(medicineList);
                    var myMedicineJsonList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<medicines>(myMedicineJson);
                    var medications = myMedicineJsonList.Value<JObject>("Medicine").ToObject<List<medicines>>();
                    var medicationsdb = entities.Set<Call_info_Medicines>();
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
```

However in `myMedicineJsonList` or in `medications` I can't get the contents of `medicineList` to store them in a table.

The table I want to store it is the following:

```
public partial class Call_info_Medicines
    {
        public int medicine_info_id { get; set; }
        public string medicine { get; set; }
        public string medicineType { get; set; }
        public string medicineDosage { get; set; }
        public string medicinePlace { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to store it using the following line is the previous code snipset.

```
 var medicationsdb = entities.Set<Call_info_Medicines>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

```
public class RootObject
    {
        public List<medicines> Medicine { get; set; }
    }

var medResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(medicineList);
var medicineTypeL = medResult.Medicine.Select(p => p.medicineType).ToList();
var medicineDosageL = medResult.Medicine.Select(p => p.medicineDosage).ToList();
var medicinePlaceL = medResult.Medicine.Select(p => p.medicinePlace).ToList();
```